# JQuery countdown timer delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, countdown

I have implemented the JQuery Countdown Timer (jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js). Am facing the delay in the timer in different machines and same machine different browsers. Sometimes it take 40-50 seconds delay in total 15 mins. The javascript logic is defined below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var Timer;

    function CreateTimer(TimerID, Time){
            Timer = document.getElementById(TimerID);
    TotalSeconds = Time;

    UpdateTimer();
    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
}
function Tick() {
    TotalSeconds -= 1;
    if(TotalSeconds>=0){
        UpdateTimer();
        window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);
    }else{
            // NO TIME THEN LOGOUT
                    //          alert(SUCCESS_LOGOUT);
    }
}
function UpdateTimer() {
        var Seconds = TotalSeconds;

    var Days = Math.floor(Seconds / 86400);
    Seconds -= Days * 86400;

    var Hours = Math.floor(Seconds / 3600);
    Seconds -= Hours * (3600);

    var Minutes = Math.floor(Seconds / 60);
    Seconds -= Minutes * (60);


    var TimeStr = "" +((Days > 0) ? Days + " days " : "") + LeadingZero(Hours) + ":" + LeadingZero(Minutes) + ":" + LeadingZero(Seconds)+"<b>"
    Timer.innerHTML = TimeStr;
}

function LeadingZero(Time) {
    return (Time < 10) ? "0" + Time : + Time;
}

</script>
```

This above code is of javascript. I can't find any resolution for timer getting delayed.
Is there anything am missing?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is two issues with your code:

```
1. window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000); here you are passing a string you need to 
                                      pass  a function 
2. you need a global variable for TotalSeconds
```

i'm not sure what this code does, however here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/qmEh9/)

Comment: 1. Passing string doesn't affect the function to be called. It gets invoked after 1000 milliseconds.
2. Yes the TotalSeconds have been defined globally.

I think there might be something related to Machine Processes or browser's process which causes delay in time.